# gnuplot undefined symbol in c

Tags: snap, c, gnuplot

I have a c program to plot a simple gaussian distribution. However, whenever I call the program I get this error:

`gnuplot: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE`

Please help

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask the people that made this app.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Core, or a regular Ubuntu with a snap version of gnuplot? Are you calling the gnuplot executable from your code, or using the C/C++ API? The error message suggests that the versions of libpthread and libc are incompatible.

Comment: @steeldriver I am using a regular ubuntu (22.04). The executable is run from my code. On its own, gnuplot works fine